# ruby method 'each' not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, methods, each

I'm trying to get a list of a users friends at random, however the "each" method doesn't seem to work when I try to use each id. Please help.

My code:

```
def get_friendsids_from (user, num_to_gather)
  userid_file = File.new("friends_ids.txt","a")
  friends_list = client.friends(user).take(num_to_gather).sample
  friends_list.each {|idnumber|
    puts idnumber.followers_count
    #puts client.user(idnumber).id
    puts idnumber.screen_name
    userid_file.puts "#{idnumber.id}"  
  }
end


get_friendsids_from("user", 5)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
twitter.rb:94:in `get_friendsids_from': undefined method `each' for #<Twitter::User id=2343746551> (NoMethodError)
    from twitter.rb:103:in `<main>'
```

Thank you for your time and consideration :)

Answer (score 3):

Because `friends_list` is a record, not an array, so it doesn't have `each` method.

`sample: Choose a random element from the array`

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
a.sample         #=> 7 # You just get one element ,not an array.
a.sample(4)      #=> [6, 4, 2, 5]
```

Comment: Because friends_list is a record, not an array, so it does't have each method

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def get_friendsids_from (user, num_to_gather)
  userid_file = File.new("friends_ids.txt","a")
  friends_list = client.friends(user).take(num_to_gather)
  friends_list.each {|idnumber|
    puts idnumber.followers_count
    #puts client.user(idnumber).id
    puts idnumber.screen_name
    userid_file.puts "#{idnumber.id}"  
  }
end


get_friendsids_from("user", 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this -

```
 def get_friendsids_from (user, num_to_gather)
   userid_file = File.new("friends_ids.txt","a")
   friends_list = client.friends(user).take(num_to_gather).sample(10)
   friends_list.each {|idnumber|
     puts idnumber.followers_count
     #puts client.user(idnumber).id
     puts idnumber.screen_name
     userid_file.puts "#{idnumber.id}"  
   }
 end


 get_friendsids_from("user", 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

just change this line

```
friends_list = client.friends(user).take(num_to_gather).sample
```

to this

```
friends_list = client.friends(user).sample(num_to_gather)
```